# Google map not working in IE8 (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

No idea why... works fine on every other browser and platform.

I've had a good long look around the net and have attempted a few suggested fixes here but this seems to be a new issue to what has already been posted. I'm hoping someone can help.

Example page: http://greenleavesmarketing.co.uk/sherif/contact/

Header.php :

```
<?php //Map 

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var locations = [
      [\'';

    if($options['custom_logo']) { 
        echo '<img src="' . $options['custom_logo'] . '" alt="';
        echo bloginfo('name');
        echo '" style="width:150px;padding: 0px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;" />';
    }

echo '<p><strong>'.$options["company"].'</strong><br />'.$options["address-one"].'<br />'.$options["address-two"].'<br />'.$options["postcode"].'</p>\', '.$options["latitude"].', '.$options["longitude"].', 1],';


if($options['latitude2'] != '') {           
echo '[\'';

    if($options['custom_logo']) { 
        echo '<img src="' . $options['custom_logo'] . '" alt="';
        echo bloginfo('name');
        echo '" style="width:150px;padding: 0px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;" />';
    }

echo '<p><strong>'.$options["company"].'</strong><br />'.$options["address-one2"].'<br />'.$options["address-two2"].'<br />'.$options["postcode2"].'</p>\', '.$options["latitude2"].', '.$options["longitude2"].', 2]'; 
}

echo '];

        window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\'map\'), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            bounds.extend(marker.position);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, \'click\', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
            map.setZoom(' . $options["zoom"] . ');
            google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
        });
    }

    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement(\'script\');
        script.type = \'text/javascript\';
        script.src = \'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&\' + \'callback=initialize\';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;





    </script>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `locations` array is being output as:

```
 var locations = [
      ['<p><strong>The London Dental Clinic</strong><br />40 Harley St<br />London<br />W1G 9PP</p>', 51.518676921614315, -0.14653116464614, 1],];
```

IE8 is treating this as an array of length 2 which is then causing an error in the loop later in your JavaScript. If you remove the comma immediately before the last `]` it should work.

You should probably change your php to:

```
if($options['custom_logo']) { 
        echo '<img src="' . $options['custom_logo'] . '" alt="';
        echo bloginfo('name');
        echo '" style="width:150px;padding: 0px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;" />';
    }

echo '<p><strong>'.$options["company"].'</strong><br />'.$options["address-one"].'<br />'.$options["address-two"].'<br />'.$options["postcode"].'</p>\', '.$options["latitude"].', '.$options["longitude"].', 1]';


if($options['latitude2'] != '') {           
    echo ', [\'';

    if($options['custom_logo']) { 
        echo '<img src="' . $options['custom_logo'] . '" alt="';
        echo bloginfo('name');
        echo '" style="width:150px;padding: 0px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;" />';
    }
```

See how I changed it to only add the comma if the second location is defined?

Note that I don't actually know PHP so I might have changed it incorrectly :)